# How to generate nested entities with freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker

I want to create a json file with nested entities using `freemarker`

How should I create the template file?

Entity(You can change this structure for convenience):

```
@Data
public class Field {
  private String name;
  private boolean isNested; // 
  private List<Field> fields;
}
```

Data:

```
|--NameA
|  false
|  null
|
|--NameB
|  false
|  null
|
|--NameC
|  true
|  |--NameD
   |--false
   |--null
   |
   |--NameE
   |--false
   |--null
```

The representation I want:

```
{
  NameA: {
    Type: NotNested  // not nested, display NotNested
  }，
  NameB: {
    Type: NotNested
  }，
  NameC: {          // nested, display nested fields
    Nested: {
      NameD: {
        Type: NotNested
      }，
      NameE: {
        Type: NotNested
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it a strict requirement to use Freemarker to generate JSON data? Tools like e.g. [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) are much more suited for this use case.

Comment: Check this, maybe can help you a little bit: https://web.liferay.com/es/web/allen.ziegenfus/blog/-/blogs/working-with-json-in-freemarker

Comment: @Koraktor This is a workaround. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
File sqlWriteFile = new File("test.json");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(sqlWriteFile);
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");

Map<String, Object> objA = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> objC = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> objB = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> objD = new HashMap<>();

// ......
objA.put("objA", objC);
objC.put("objC", objB);
objB.put("objB", objD);

objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(writer, objA);
```

Results:

```
{
  "objA":{
    "objC":{
      "objB":{
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```